# How can I show order quantity relative to cities where customers in cities have at least three orders?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I use this SQL statement to be able to join three tables (Order1, Order2, and Customers) to show the order quantity for each customer from each city they're addressed to. But how can I show the rows of order quantities for customers in cities who have done at least three orders? In other words I'm trying to aggregate on the cities connected to the customers who have done more than three orders.

Table structures:

- `Customers` has the columns `CustomerNr, City Name`
- *Order1* has the columns `Ordernr, CustomerNr`
- `Order2` has the columns `Ordernr, Order quantity`

The SQL statement so far:

```
SELECT 
    Customers.CityName, Order2.OrderQuantity
FROM 
    Order1 
INNER JOIN 
    Order2 ON Order1.ordernr = Order2.ordernr 
INNER JOIN 
    Customers ON Customers.CustomerNr = Order1.CustomerNr
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide us some sample data, concerning the input and the desired result.

Comment: The result I want is to show the rows for the cities where customers have made at least three orders, and I want to add a column (to the output view) named AS 'Total quantity' with their total orders in numbers, which you get from the column 'Orderquantity' in table Order2.

Comment: In other words: The output should be in two columns: 'City names' (listing the rows with cities where customers have made at least three orders) and 'Order Quantity', which should be a column you add AS 'Order quantity' to show the total orders to these customers. And the order quantities can be fetched from the column "orderquantity" from table 'Order2'.

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing are aggregate functions. To get the sum of a column, you can use `SUM(columnName)` in your select statement. To get proper results, you will have to group by a field as well. In this case, you want the sum per customer so you can do something like this:

```
SELECT c.customerNumber, c.name, SUM(o2.quantity) AS totalQuantity
FROM customers c
JOIN order1 o1 ON o1.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
JOIN order2 o2 ON o2.orderNumber = o1.orderNumber
GROUP BY c.customerNumber, c.name;
```

To filter on an aggregate condition, you need to add a having clause. Here, you can require that each group have a minimum of 3 rows:

```
SELECT c.customerNumber, c.name, SUM(o2.quantity) AS totalQuantity
FROM customers c
JOIN order1 o1 ON o1.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
JOIN order2 o2 ON o2.orderNumber = o1.orderNumber
GROUP BY c.customerNumber, c.name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/72309/5) with some dummy data that I tested with.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.CityName, Sum(o2.OrderQuantity) as Quantity
from   Customers c 
       inner join Order1 o1 on c.CustomerNr = o1.CustomerNr
       inner join Order2 o2 on o1.OrderNr = o2.OrderNr
group by c.CityName
having sum(o2.OrderQuantity) >= 3
```

Comment: @ecinna . . . Your question says:  "show the rows of order quantities for customers".  This answer shows summaries.  If this doesn't do what you really want, you should ask another question.  If it does, you should be clearer about your questions in the future.  Sample data and desired results always help.